# Recover files after making a Windows 10 restore point

Tags: windows-10, formatting, system-restore

I recently tried to make a Recover point of my computer, and when Windows asked me where I want to do that, I selected the hard drive where I have all of my backups (projects, documentations etc.). What I didn't read correctly (the system language is Russian) is that Windows first formats the hard drive before making a restore point, and I immediately lost all of the files.

Did anybody already encounter this problem?  If so, is there a way to restore the files?

I tried `recuva`, that already helped me in past, but even `recuva` cannot find any file...

Comment: Are you sure you actually made a 'restore point' and not something completely different (like a 'recovery disk' or perform a 'system refresh')?

Comment: No, I created a recovery point(almost sure), I remember the message said something like ''you need at least 16Gb of free space...", now on the disk I have only 2 folders "EFI" and "sources" and one file ''reagant.xml''. Some other important point, hard drive is 500Go, and I now see it as a 32Go drive, but don't want to touch anything before getting advises

Comment: @grawity any idea?

Comment: @Siegfried.V - Use any data recovery software you have access to, they are all pratically the same, any data that can be recovered should be detected.  Sadly, data recovery is not a guaranteed thing, if the data has been overwritten there is nothing that can be done.  In the future you should make sure you have valid backups of any vital information.

Comment: It might not be important any more, but just to remark that creating a restore point does not reformat the disk. See [Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Comment: @Ramhound the problem is I had all 'vital' backups on the hard drive where I wanted to make backup... I'd say in future I will avoid using such important hard drive to make any backups by Windows...

Comment: @Siegfried.V - Sounds like a case for professional data recovery, I suggest finding a data recovery service that has good reviews, I cannot (nor will I) suggest any specific company.

Comment: @Ramhound in fact I looked harrymc's link, MiniTool Power Data recovery looks good, he found 'unused partition' with all my files(recuva couldn't find it), I will see results in 7 hours, so I guess I will just rescue pdf files (documentation), for my C# projects too hard as it doesn't recover the names, and I have thousand of .cs files...

Comment: @harrymc thanks, for the link, MiniTool Power Data is a good one(as wrotten in my previous comment), the only minus is that it couldn't get the names of the files, so it is a good tool to recover big files for example, but if it is to recover C# projects it is very problematic. Thanks anyway